# How to watch/run videos served by KA_Lite server on iPod touch?

Tags: video, streaming, ipod

I am running *KA Lite(Khan Academy Lite)* on my PC and I can access the local server, log-in, browse and play the videos from it.

This same server is accessible via WiFi on my iPod touch. However, **I'm unable to play KA_Lite videos on my iPod touch 4th Generation( iOS 6.1.3)**.

The KA_Lite video's are stored in MP4 format and I can play them on iPod( with iTunes file transfer). These same video's are being streamed( by KA_Lite Server) but somehow become unplayable. I'm sure this is not a *Wifi Band-Width* problem as I have done Wifi file transfers before and played HD videos( via *VLC Streamer*).

Has anyone successfully played KA_lite server streamed videos on their iDevices ??

Comment: VLC for iOS might help.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I tried. Didn't help. It seems that it can be done with a browser/based player as we have to connect to the server first( like 192.168.1.5:8008 ), then we can browse and play video's. VLC has a Stream Playing option but it didn't work/support KA_Lite, as KA_Lite is not a video streamer but a web server. I think the term **streaming** is quite confusion( I have edited the title to make it more clear ).

Answer (score 1):

try installing the Khan Academy iOS app on the iPhone instead.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/khan-academy/id469863705

You should be able to play the video streams right from within the app instead of using the Safari or Chrome apps.

Comment: I installed this iOS app but it has nothing to do with *KA Lite*.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple suggestions.

Dropbox will stream mp4s from your server by way of a symlink to the Dropbox folder, or directly from your Dropbox folder if you copy the videos there.

The videos for KA are available on YouTube and can be watched there.

KA Lite is designed for locations in the third world that have no internet access and want a self-contained KA install. If their video streaming will not work then the KA Lite group on GitHub May be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use MoliPlayer and it works great! https://itunes.apple.com/GB/app/id488691300

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi. I couldn't play the video's using the suggested application. How do you access the server (eg. @ **192.168.1.2:8008** )? In *Safari* or *Chrome* I could just enter the above IP( **192.168.1.2:8008** ) and Browse the content(Video playback doesn't works!). How do you do it in MoliPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution.  On further experimenting/wandering/trying I **SUCCEEDED** playing a couple of video's through going inside the **READER** option on iOS native browser **safari** :) !

But this does not work for long as the playback button disappears. Here are some SNAPS

[image: Here's the READER Option]

[image: Here is playback button]

[image: I CAN PLAY VIDEO :)]

[image: Happiness doesn't lasts long :(]

After the playback button disappears, I have to close the page and restart the **safari browser** then again I have to browse inside the video library to play the video.
At one time only 2-3 video's can be played consecutively on my device( 4th gen iPOD). After that I have to again reload and browse, this wastes time !!!